# History of Study's Lemma?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, algebraic-curves, classical-invariant-theory

The following theorem is usually attributed to [Eduard Study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Study):

> Let $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ be polynomials in two variables over a field, with $f$ irreducible. If $f\nmid g$ then the curves $C_f:f=0$ and $C_g:g=0$ have finitely many points of intersection. Consequently, If the field is algebraically closed and $C_f\subseteq C_g$ (hence $C_f\cap C_g$ has infinitely many points) then $f|g$.

However, I have not been able to track down any reference to this result outside of modern textbooks.

Questions:

- What is the original reference for this result?
- What did Study actually prove?
- What was the context?
- Did this result directly influence later versions of the Nullstellensatz?

Thanks.

Edit: I see that Study wrote a book on on the [Theory of Ternary Forms](https://archive.org/details/methodenzurtheo00studgoog/page/n6/mode/2up) (1889). I suppose the result must be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the lemma on page 63 of Study's [Einleitung in die Theorie der Invarianten linearer Transformationen auf Grund der Vektorenrechnung](https://archive.org/details/einleitungindiet01studuoft/page/62/mode/2up) (1923).

[image]

The source cited for the proof is page 202 of Study's [Methoden zur Theorie der ternären Formen](https://archive.org/details/methodenzurtheo00studgoog/page/n220/mode/2up?q=teilbar) (1889), where it appears as an [endnote](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/Eduard_Study_2.png) and refers to a "less elementary" proof by

> O. Hölder, Z*um Invariantenbegriff*, Math. Naturwiss. Mitteilungen
> **1**, 59–65 (1884).

Volume 1 of the [journal](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=au%3AMathematisch-Naturwissenschaftlicher+Verein+in+W%C3%BCrtemberg%2C+Stuttgart.&qt=hot_author) is not online, but there is a review at [zbMath](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A16.0092.02) [thanks, @spin] that explicitly mentions the lemma:

> Sind die ganzen rationalen Functionen $F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)$,
> $G(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)$ so beschaffen, dass für alle (reellen oder
> complexen) Wertsysteme $x_1,x_2,x_m$, wofür $G=0$ ist, auch die
> Gleichung $F=0$ gilt, und ist G irreduzibel, so ist $G$  ein Teiler
> von $F$.
>  <sub>Let the entire rational functions $F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)$ and
> $G(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)$ be such, that for any (real or complex) values $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_m$ where $G=0$ also $F=0$, and let $G$ be irreducible, then $G$ divides $F$.</sub>

It's too late (and not productive) to change common practice, but priority wise I would conclude that Study's lemma is Hölder's lemma.

Comment: Review of Hölder's paper "Zum Invariantenbegriff": [link](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A16.0092.02)